# IRC Web Based Front For My Server

Tags: open-source

I would like an open source application for the server at my house that tracks my favorite IRC channels and allows me to display and chat using a GUI interface.

https://webchat.freenode.net interface is exactly what I am talking about.  Simple textbox at the bottom and displaying of information.

I want it to have mostly importantly chat history though.

Comment: By what criteria would accept or reject a suggested solution?

Comment: @BasilBourque If it meets the requirements it will be accepted unless it has some absurd requirement software wise.  I don't want a terminal application.

Comment: You did not really list any requirements is the problem, other than “open source”. What server architecture (CPU, memory)? What OS? What programming language? What cost? What security is necessary?

Comment: @BasilBourque open source implies free. OS linux because its a server and free. Security I mean its to be used on my local area connection so not really important.

Comment: No open-source does not imply free-of-cost.

Comment: @BasilBourque a one time fee would be acceptable but nothing reoccurring.